# Problema al llamar un metodo de otra clase en el main

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ropa extends Generico{
    private String talla;
    private String tipo;
    private String color;
    private int cantidad;

    public Ropa (double precio, String tipoUnidad, String talla, String tipo, String color, int cantidad) {

        super(precio, tipoUnidad);

        this.talla = talla;  
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.color = color;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
         }

    public void setTalla(String talla){
        if (talla != null) {
            this.talla = talla;
        }else{
            System.out.println("talla vacia o invalida");
        }
    }
    public String getTalla(){
        return talla;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo){
        if (tipo != null) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingresa el tipo de prenda que es");
        }

    }
    public String getTipo(){
        return tipo;

    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        if (color != null) {
            this.color = color;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingresa el color de la prenda");
        }

    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;

    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad){
        if (cantidad < 0) {
            this.cantidad = cantidad;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingresa la cantidad de prendas");
        }

    }
    public int getCantidad(){
        return cantidad;

    }
    public static ArrayList getimprimirRopa(){
        ArrayList<Ropa> ropita = new ArrayList<Ropa>();
        ropita.add(new Ropa(120.30, "piezas", "Grande", "Camisa tipo polo", "Rojo", 1));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(170.90, "piezas", "chico", "Pantalon de vestir", "Cafe", 1));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(600, "piezas", "Extra-Grande", "Chamarra piel", "Negro", 1));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(200.10, "piezas", "Extra-chico", "Playera", "Blanco", 1));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(150.60, "piezas", "Mediano", "Short", "Azul", 1));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(130.10, "piezas", "Grande", "Calcetines", "Verde", 2));
        ropita.add(new Ropa(250.55, "piezas", "Extra-Grande", "Pantalon mezclilla", "Azul marino", 1));

        return ropita;

    }

}
```

// solo en la clase comprador existira main

Comment: Necesito saber como llamar el metodo public static ArrayList getimprimirRopa() en mi clase comprador que tendra el main

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es algo confusa, no sé que tienes en el main.
Pero no olvides instanciar un objeto de la clase para poder usar sus métodos, aquí una pequeña guía para eso: [Instanciar objetos en java](https://javautodidacta.es/instanciar-un-objeto-en-java/)